# Looking for embedded project with source code

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I have embedded developement board (LPCXXXX) with me. I would like to do various experiments with that. I am not getting experiment ideas.

Please suggest me some good websites where I will get some good project/experiment ideas. I am looking for embedded system projects with source code in internet.
I am unable to find it.
Please help me where I will get embedded system project with source code (Video tutorial is an added advantage)

:-In tag I have added C because I did not find EmbeddedC tag.

Comment: [Invent a device that stabs people in the face over the Internet.](http://bash.org/?4281)

Comment: you know how to program the board/device you have and you are looking for ideas on what to program.  Or you dont know how to program the device/board you have and you want to learn how to write programs for it?

Comment: @dwelch: I would like to learn how to write the program for it.

Comment: LPCxxxx is a broad range encompassing Cortex-M0,3 & 4 as well as ARM7 & 9 parts.  You probably ought to be more specific about the devices you will be using since these are very different processors, and not likely all supported by your board.

Comment: Regarding the tag, C is a programming language, Embedded C simply refers to the use of C on an embedded system (i.e. it is not a distinct language), so the tag is fine.  I would in fact suggest that perhaps you have "over tagged"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Martin Thomas's ARM Projects](http://gandalf.arubi.uni-kl.de/avr_projects/arm_projects/) site for a number of projects specifically for various LPC devices and also other ARM micro-controllers which could easily be adapted for LPC.

Comment: @cshapler:  Your addition to my answer is worthy of either a comment or an answer of your own.  Since I have never used the site you mentioned in the edit to my answer I cannot let it stand associated with me and have rolled it back.

Answer (score 0):

That's a rather broad question as you don't give much about what aspects of the embedded project you're looking for.  The Kernel?  The OS (making it small with things like [busybox](http://busybox.net/))?

But one good reference might be the [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) project you might have heard about recently.  It has it's linux kernel published, along with all the necessary OS components.

Comment: LPCxxxx covers a wide range, much of which is not capable of supporting a Linux kernel.